# How can I achieve the R kernel density estimate plot using D3.js?

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, kernel-density

This is my R code:

```
x <- c(5.89,6.81,6.69,7.61,5.44,6.17)
y <- c(1,0.09392423,0.07090779,0.0687634,0.06819157,0.06261615)

plot(density(x, bw=0.050, adjust=1, kernel="gaussian",weights=(y),n=1000))
```

I'm trying to achieve the same result using D3.js or any other equivalent JavaScript library..

Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 7):

Have you seen the [kernel density estimation](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4341954) example?

[image: kernel density estimation]

Admittedly it uses the Epanechnikov kernel rather than Gaussian, but that part could be modified.

Comment: Thanks, that was useful... although the main problem I'm facing is the "weights=(y)" part of the R script. I can't find a decent solution!